# I'd barely said my name before he (have/had) slapped me

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, subjunctives

Consider the following three sentences:

> I'd barely said my name before he slapped me.

> I'd barely said my name before he **had** slapped me.

> I'd barely said my name before he **have** slapped me.

Is there any difference in meaning between the three versions, with a *simple past, present perfect*  and a *past perfect* ?

Secondly, does substituting **before** for **when** affect those meanings?

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. If you REALLY want to ask both questions, ask them separately.

Comment: @gotube I think we could extend a *little* bit of flexibility on the 'multiple questions' close reason. Do you really want him to post a separate question with the second part? What good does that do anybody? Surely it's just two parts of the same enquiry?

Comment: These are two unrelated questions that coincidentally use the same sentences as examples, as if the second question occurred to the OP as they were writing the first, or they crafted one example sentence that could serve to ask two unrelated questions about. The first question is about verb tenses, and the second is about conjunctions of time order, which are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give numbers to these sentences for reference.

(1) *I'd barely said my name before he slapped me.*

(2) *I'd barely said my name before he has slapped me.*

(3) *I'd barely said my name before he had slapped me.*

(4) *I'd barely said my name when he slapped me.*

(5) *I'd barely said my name when he has slapped me.*

(6) *I'd barely said my name when he had slapped me.*

Sentences (2), (5) and (6) are impossible, and there is little if any difference in meaning between (1), (3) and (4). The reason the past perfect is possible with *before* is that (3) brings to mind something like the creation of a new state in which he had already slapped you. Perhaps (3) evokes even more strongly than (1) and (4) the instantaneous nature of his action, as we do not, literally speaking, mention his action occurring but instead the state in which the action had already occurred.

Incidentally, one would say "replacing *before* with *when*" "changing *before* to *when*," or, perhaps less commonly, "changing *before* for *when*."

Edit:

I agree with your comment. Consider:

(7) I had barely said my name before he led me to the interview room.

(8) I had barely said my name before he had led me to the interview room.

The difference here is a bit more perceptible than between (1) and (3). Sentence (8) clearly refers to the end of the process of leading you to the interview room, whereas (7) refers to the process as a whole, and the time of the "leading" action is most likely to be interpreted as the beginning of the process.

Comment: @GJC This is analogous to (3), which I've said is possible.

Comment: Apparently a potentially long action like _lead someone to another room_ is different from a sudden like a _slap_  https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/id-barely-said-my-name-before-he-have-had-slapped-me.3851274/post-19686181

Comment: You should say: "substituting *when* for *before*." Also, you mean "a sudden *one*."

Comment: You **substitute** new parts **for** the old ones (but _replace_ old ones **with** new ones?) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substitute#Usage_notes

Comment: @GJC Yes, that's right. The usage note in the link shows that some people use *substitute* with the same meaning as *replace*, but then the preposition used is *by* or *with*, not *for*. This doesn't sound elegant to me, but according to the usage note, this use of *substitute* is now accepted. Before seeing the link, I'd assumed it was a mistake, which I'm sure some others do too.

Comment: From the MWDEU: "Given its use in general, and even sometimes scholarly, writing and its presence in the language for more than 300 years, we see no reason to dismiss this use of *substitute* as an error, and it has been recognized as standard in Merriam-Webster dictionaries since Webster's Second (1934). On the other hand, it is the less common sense of the word, and to some ears it will sound less than idiomatic. Faced with this potential for a negative reaction, you may want to avoid this sense of *substitute*, but worries about confused meaning need not concern you. The choice of...

Comment: "preposition almost always makes the meaning clear. The older sense of *substitute* is used with *for* ('substitute a new version for the old one'); the 'replace' sense is used with *by* or *with* ('substitute the old version with (or by) a new one')."

Comment: On the other hand, the OED Supplement (1986), called this use of *substitute* incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the three versions are possible. Both make the situation clear.

Firstly, at some point in the past, you told a man (boy?) your name.
Immediately afterwards, (for whatever reason) this person slapped you.

Whether you use **before** or **when** to link the two clauses makes no difference to the meaning.

You cannot say **before he have/has slapped me**. That's just wrong.

It's possible to use the simple past (he slapped me) or the past perfect (he had slapped me).

The choice of tense does not affect the meaning. But the past perfect gives it a more distant feel - as though the incident took place some time ago.